# I want to drop a portion of my url (php variable in the $_GET) when linking to another page

Tags: php

When i click on my table results from an individual sql query.

```
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['zip1']);

$near = "select id, first, last, trainer_address1, CITY, STATE, trainer_zip "
    "from event.ACS.trainer where trainer zip ='{$zip}'";
echo lookup_gen::query_results_table($near, matry::base_to('acs/trainer/edit&trainer_id'));
```

`query_results_table` just builds the table and rows and allows individual linking for whatever result/row is clicked on.

`matry::base_to` just Links from the base path.
    return A link from the base path to the specified path.

the current page i'm on is:

```
index.php?q=event/form&id=19471
```

it has this id variable in the $_GET as shown above.

When i click through on my query_results_table i've set up matry::base_to to link me to

```
index.php?q=acs/trainer/edit&trainer_id&id=19471
```

How can i drop the `&id=19471` in the end of that url.

Should i use unset or is there a more concise way of going about it, if any at all?

Additionally, if anyone would like me to post the query_results_table function or the matry::base_to function, i'd be more than happy too. Hope I can get this resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) hole there. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: it's not on the internet, internal stuff, i'll escape it later.

Comment: Doesn't matter. it's still entirely possible to inject yourself. e.g. `zip1=O'Brien`.

Comment: This is true, but i won't do that.

Comment: That makes it a bit more lovely. =]

Comment: what's good in escaping a string of you use the unescaped version in your query?

Comment: fixed. sorry, please let me know if you see anything else.

Comment: you cannot really edit the url that way. Get it via $_SERVER to do all the manipulation you need.

Comment: I need help with the question at hand. Any and all help and feedback is helpful too with other problems. I appreciate everyone pointing out the other things too.